# How can I filter a double array and return an object in React?

Tags: javascript

I have an array object in a variable called maintemp.

```
const maintemp = [
[
    {
    equipId: 1,
    name: '1메인 온도 센서',
    sensors: [
        {
        tagId: 11,
        name: '온도',
        value: 28.8,
        tagClass: {
            bitCalcYn: 'N',
            code: 'INNERTEMP',
            encoding: 'ONEDECIMALPOINT',
            isDigital: 'N',
        },
        },
    ],
    },
    {
    equipId: 2,
    name: '1메인 습도 센서',
    sensors: [
        {
        tagId: 22,
        name: '습도',
        value: 50.3,
        tagClass: {
            bitCalcYn: 'N',
            code: 'INNERAHUM',
            encoding: 'ONEDECIMALPOINT',
            isDigital: 'N',
            name: '실내 습도',
        },
        },
    ],
    },
],

[
    {
    equipId: 3,
    name: '2메인 온도 센서',
    sensors: [
        {
        tagId: 11,
        name: '온도',
        value: 28.8,
        tagClass: {
            bitCalcYn: 'N',
            code: 'INNERTEMP',
            encoding: 'ONEDECIMALPOINT',
            isDigital: 'N',
        },
        },
    ],
    },
    {
    equipId: 4,
    name: '2메인 습도 센서',
    sensors: [
        {
        tagId: 22,
        name: '습도',
        value: 50.3,
        tagClass: {
            bitCalcYn: 'N',
            code: 'INNERAHUM',
            encoding: 'ONEDECIMALPOINT',
            isDigital: 'N',
            name: '실내 습도',
        },
        },
    ],
    },
],
];
```

At this time, I want to put only the object whose tagClass.code is 'INNERTEMP' into the variable fill by using the map function and the filter function.

However, when I run my code, the entire array is not filtered and the entire array is stored in the fill variable. How do I fix the code?

this is my code

```
const fill = maintemp.filter((v) =>
  v.filter((hi) => hi.sensors[0].tagClass.code === "INNERTEMP'")
);
```

expected answer

```
const fill = [
    {
        equipId: 1,
        name: '1메인 온도 센서',
        sensors: [
        {
            tagId: 11,
            name: '온도',
            value: 28.8,
            tagClass: {
            bitCalcYn: 'N',
            code: 'INNERTEMP',
            encoding: 'ONEDECIMALPOINT',
            isDigital: 'N',
            },
        },
        ],
    },
    {
        equipId: 3,
        name: '2메인 온도 센서',
        sensors: [
        {
            tagId: 11,
            name: '온도',
            value: 28.8,
            tagClass: {
            bitCalcYn: 'N',
            code: 'INNERTEMP',
            encoding: 'ONEDECIMALPOINT',
            isDigital: 'N',
            },
        },
        ],
    },

]
```

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple `sensors` entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first flatten your array then filter items:

```
fill = maintemp.flat().filter((hi) => hi.sensors[0].tagClass.code === "INNERTEMP")
```

```js
const maintemp = [[{"equipId":1,"name":"1메인 온도 센서","sensors":[{"tagId":11,"name":"온도","value":28.8,"tagClass":{"bitCalcYn":"N","code":"INNERTEMP","encoding":"ONEDECIMALPOINT","isDigital":"N"}}]},{"equipId":2,"name":"1메인 습도 센서","sensors":[{"tagId":22,"name":"습도","value":50.3,"tagClass":{"bitCalcYn":"N","code":"INNERAHUM","encoding":"ONEDECIMALPOINT","isDigital":"N","name":"실내 습도"}}]}],[{"equipId":3,"name":"2메인 온도 센서","sensors":[{"tagId":11,"name":"온도","value":28.8,"tagClass":{"bitCalcYn":"N","code":"INNERTEMP","encoding":"ONEDECIMALPOINT","isDigital":"N"}}]},{"equipId":4,"name":"2메인 습도 센서","sensors":[{"tagId":22,"name":"습도","value":50.3,"tagClass":{"bitCalcYn":"N","code":"INNERAHUM","encoding":"ONEDECIMALPOINT","isDigital":"N","name":"실내 습도"}}]}]];

const fill = maintemp.flat().filter((hi) => hi.sensors[0].tagClass.code === "INNERTEMP")

console.log(fill)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the suggestion didn't have that at top of my mind! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Need to flat array then filter

```js
const maintemp = [
[
    {
    equipId: 1,
    name: '1메인 온도 센서',
    sensors: [
        {
        tagId: 11,
        name: '온도',
        value: 28.8,
        tagClass: {
            bitCalcYn: 'N',
            code: 'INNERTEMP',
            encoding: 'ONEDECIMALPOINT',
            isDigital: 'N',
        },
        },
    ],
    },
    {
    equipId: 2,
    name: '1메인 습도 센서',
    sensors: [
        {
        tagId: 22,
        name: '습도',
        value: 50.3,
        tagClass: {
            bitCalcYn: 'N',
            code: 'INNERAHUM',
            encoding: 'ONEDECIMALPOINT',
            isDigital: 'N',
            name: '실내 습도',
        },
        },
    ],
    },
],

[
    {
    equipId: 3,
    name: '2메인 온도 센서',
    sensors: [
        {
        tagId: 11,
        name: '온도',
        value: 28.8,
        tagClass: {
            bitCalcYn: 'N',
            code: 'INNERTEMP',
            encoding: 'ONEDECIMALPOINT',
            isDigital: 'N',
        },
        },
    ],
    },
    {
    equipId: 4,
    name: '2메인 습도 센서',
    sensors: [
        {
        tagId: 22,
        name: '습도',
        value: 50.3,
        tagClass: {
            bitCalcYn: 'N',
            code: 'INNERAHUM',
            encoding: 'ONEDECIMALPOINT',
            isDigital: 'N',
            name: '실내 습도',
        },
        },
    ],
    },
],
];



let fill = maintemp.flatMap(obj => obj).filter(obj =>obj.sensors.filter(s =>s.tagClass.code ==='INNERTEMP').length !==0);

console.log(fill)
```